# Call PHP inbuilt function dynamically using function name string

Tags: php

I need to format a given value as an integer of float. For that I am using `intval()` & `intfloat()` functions in PHP.

For both operations I need to use one function.

```
function formatValue($value, $functionString){
  return $functionString === 'intval' ? intval($value) : floatval($value);
}
```

Is there a way to shorter this function? I need to call the function directly from the `$functionString` like,

```
function formatValue($value, $functionString){
  return {$functionString}($value);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array)

Comment: I’m assuming `intfloat` is supposed to be `floatval`?

Comment: Please show how you want to call `formatValue`. Also, what is wrong with the first way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the curly braces:

```
function formatValue($value, $functionString){
    return $functionString($value);
}
```

See [Variable Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for reference.

Please note that recent PHP versions will throw an [`Error` throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) if something goes wrong.